# how to set tablayout icon using fontawesome

Tags: android, font-awesome, android-tablayout

I am a beginner in android.I am using font-awesome library for icons. I want to set the icon using font-awesome in `tablyout` using view pager

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an xml layout named custom_tab.xml

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    />
```

Now set font of tab layout using below code

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("&#xf1fe;");
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
tabOne.setTypeface(typeface);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

**[How to Use FontAwesome in an Android App](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167)**

Comment: implement the above and worked, unfortunately, the icons are aligned left. How to keep the icons aligned center ??